# How to handle error when a column being looked is missing

Tags: vba, excel

I have this runtime error 13 when this code is executed:

```
Dim rng As Range, rngx As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastRowx As Long
Dim col As Long, colx As Long
Dim a As Double, b As Double

With ActiveSheet

    Set rng = Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A9:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
    col = Application.Match("*COMMUNICATIONS*", rng, 0)
    LastRow = Sheets("COMPAS").Cells(1000000, col).End(xlUp).Row

End With

a = Sheets("COMPAS").Cells(LastRow, col)


With ActiveSheet

    Set rngx = Sheets("COMPAS").Range("A9:" & .Range("ZZ9").End(xlToRight).Address)
    colx = Application.Match("*SLOPCHEST*", rng, 0)
    LastRowx = Sheets("COMPAS").Cells(1000000, col).End(xlUp).Row

End With

b = Sheets("COMPAS").Cells(LastRowx, colx)

Sheets("MACRO TEMPLATE").Cells(11, 2) = a + b
```

My code finds the column "COMMUNICATIONS" and determine its last row value. Same way with the column "SLOPCHEST". If "COMMUNICATIONS" is missing, then the value will be the value of "SLOPCHEST" only and vice versa. If both of the columns are there, then it will be added.

My problem is that when column "COMMUNICATIONS" or "SLOPCHEST" is missing, it gives me an error. How can I handle the error for when a column is missing, it will still give me my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try catching the error produced by *no Match.*

```
col = Application.Match("*COMMUNICATIONS*", rng, 0)
If IsError(col) Then
    'not found
Else
    'do what you want         
End If

colx = Application.Match("*SLOPCHEST*", rng, 0)
If IsError(colx) Then
    'not found
Else    
    'do what you want, set a value you need        
End If
```

If both values are not found, you may need to set a default value or assign as per your requirement. [Reference.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213643)

Comment: As per my above code, your `col`, `colx` should come inside the `else` clause. Let me know if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. It works now. I just place col, and lastrow, and a to the else clause.